# Change icon of website and center gallery of images in c#

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net

I'm building a website in asp.net , c#.
I have a gallery of severall images but I can't center it on the page. 
The gallery looks like this:
[Gallery of images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nuiuk.png)

I would like something like this: [Example that I made in the wix site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PUb3L.png)

My style code is:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <style>
        body {
            font-size: 13px;
            font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        }

        h2 {
            font-size: 21px;
            color: #008000;
        }

        p {
            text-align: justify;
        }

        div.gallery {
            display: block;
            margin: 10px;
            float: left;
            text-align: center;
            width: 252px;
        }

            /*passar o rato*/

            div.gallery:hover {  
                /*border: 1px solid #777;*/
            }

            div.gallery img {
                width: 252px;
                height: 120px;
                border: 1px solid #111;
            }

        div.desc {
            padding: 15px;
            text-align: center;
        }
    </style>

    <h2>FUTEBOL</h2>
    <div class="gallery">
        <a target="_blank" href="Heliflex.jpg">
            <img src="~/Imagens/Slide DS.jpg" alt="DOMO Slide DS">
        </a>
        <div class="desc">DOMO® Slide DS</div>
    </div>

    <div class="gallery">
        <a target="_blank" href="VarioSlide S Pro test2.jpg">
            <img src="~/Imagens/Slide RS.jpg" alt="DOMO Slide RS">
        </a>
        <div class="desc">DOMO® Slide RS &#8594; </div>
    </div>

    <div class="gallery">
        <a target="_blank" href="naturafill.jpg">
            <img src="~/Imagens/DuraForce XSL.jpg" alt="DOMO Duraforce XSL">
        </a>
        <div class="desc">DOMO® Duraforce XSL &#8594; </div>
    </div>

    <div class="gallery">
        <a target="_blank" href="DOMO FastPlay.jpg">
            <img src="~/Imagens/DuraForce XQ.jpg" alt="Domo Duraforce XQ">
        </a>
        <div class="desc">DOMO® Duraforce XQ &#8594; </div>
    </div>

    <div class="gallery">
        <a target="_blank" href="">
            <img src="~/Imagens/DOMO VarioSlide S ProFut.jpg" alt="Domo VarioSlide S Pro">
        </a>
        <div class="desc">DOMO® VarioSlide S Pro &#8594; </div>
    </div>

    <div class="gallery">
        <a target="_blank" href="DOMO FastPlay.jpg">
            <img src="~/Imagens/DuraForce XT.jpg" alt="Domo Duraforce XT">
        </a>
        <div class="desc">DOMO® Duraforce XT &#8594; </div>
    </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

I've already search at the w3schools website but I can't find the answer. 
Also, and sorry if it is silly, I don't know how can I change the icon of the website. [This right here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BsW2V.png)

Can someone explain that to me, please?
Thank you for you time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set a icon image name of `favicon.ico` on site root `/favicon.ico`

Add this on **Header** tag in your html.

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="~/favicon.ico" />
```

You can use [FavIcon Generator](http://tools.dynamicdrive.com/favicon/) to Generator your icon

Comment: Great, thank you! :) What about the first question, any answer?

Comment: Sorry I didn't see your first question. Could you give me more explain about center it on the page? and Could you show me your images html code?

Comment: I saw the example from  **wix site** could you give me the example link?

Comment: you can refer this link https://jsfiddle.net/xb6gzogd/  wish can help you @M.Carreira

Comment: Ok, I'll see! Thank you :)

Comment: Yes, I forgot! Done! :)